# Import several existing resources in Terraform state takes very long time

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to import several resources by creating a scripts which read AWS resources and then import in Terraform state file using `terraform import`. The fact is that it takes ages because the `import` command upload at every call the changes to the remote state in S3. Do you have any idea how to approach in a different way the problem?

Comment: you can import to local state file.

Comment: and then do a push right? @BMW

Comment: @BMW I've been trying but without any luck. The command always upload the state file remotely

Comment: why? if you don’t set s3 as backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to disable the remote state (delete the S3 state and keep a copy just in case), then import to the local path the state and once you finish all the imports you can configure the backend again and run  `terraform init -reconfigure` then terraform will ask you to upload the local state to S3.

```
/Users/koe/.terraform-versions/terraform-0.9.11/terraform init -reconfigure
Initializing the backend...
Do you want to copy state from "local" to "s3"?
  Pre-existing state was found in "local" while migrating to "s3". No existing
  state was found in "s3". Do you want to copy the state from "local" to
  "s3"? Enter "yes" to copy and "no" to start with an empty state.

  Enter a value:
```